# How can I chang the text of all controls on form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form (Form1,form2)
this code on form2 ...
I make a loop of all controls on form1 and get name of the control (ControlName)
I want send any text (ex."sherif") to this control (case button)

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in form1.Controls)
{
    form1.Controls[ControlName]).Text = "sherif";
}
```

error message appears
NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if the pointer stop above [ControlName] read name of control, but when continue
Comes an Null value

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error. And if you are doing a foreach over those controls, just use ctrl.Text = "sherif"; within your foreach

Comment: Controls could be nested within other controls, like Panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the `Text` properties of all controls in a form, this should do it:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in form1.Controls)
{
   ctrl.Text = "sherif";
}
```

Note this will only change the controls in the top level and not nested controls....

If you need this for nested controls too, do it recursively:

```
 public void RecursiveChange(Control control)       
 {

    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
       RecursiveChange(ctrl);
       ctrl.Text = "sherif";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method recursively returns all controls of form:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(Control parent)
{
    foreach(Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return ctrl;

        if (ctrl.HasChildren)
            yield return GetChildControls(ctrl);
    }
}
```

Updating text:

```
foreach(var ctrl in GetChildControls(form1))
    ctrl.Text = "sherif";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop all controls. Some of them can be inside panels.
 Use this recursive method:

```
private void SetText(Control control, string text)       
{
     foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
     {
         ctrl.Text = text;
         SetText(ctrl, text);
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
SetText(form1,  "sherif");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
{

    if (c!= null)
    {
        c.text="Sherif";
    }
}
```